# Is there a way to tell chrome dev tools to break anywhere in a file?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints

I know control will pass through a file.

But I don't know where, as there are *a lot* of functions and conditionals in it, so I'd have to manually put breakpoints on almost every single line.

Is there a way I can tell Chrome Dev Tools to do that for me, or, in other words, to stop execution as soon as control enters the file anywhere in it?

---

From [this official overview](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/) I would assume the answer is no, but maybe somebody knows a trick?

Comment: You could profile your JavaScript to determine which functions are being called and when. You can then use that info to set appropriate breakpoints.